# Does the this converse of the MVT hold true for harmonic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded connected open region in $\Bbb R^n$, and $u$ is merely *continuous* on $\Omega$ that satisfies this MVT:
$$u(x_0)=\frac1{|S_r(x_0)|}\int_{S_r(x_0)}u(y)dy$$
where $S_r(x_0)$ is the sphere of radius $r$ centred at $x_0$ and lies within $U$. Then is it true that $\Delta u=0$ in all of $U$?

The only difficulty lies in proving that $u$ is actually $C^2$ i.e. $\Delta u$ should at least exist and be continuous.

---

Background: this problem comes from an attempt to prove Harnack's first theorem, which asserts that if a sequence of functions $\{u_k\}$ are $C(\bar U)$ and are harmonic in $U$ and converge uniformly on $\partial U$, then they also converge uniformly to a continuous function $u$ on $\bar U$ which is harmonic in $U$.

My attempt: first use Cauchy's criteria to write something like $|u_m(x)-u_n(x)|<\epsilon$ on $\partial U$, then since $u_m-u_n$ is harmonic and thus satisfies the strong maximum principle, therefore the above inequality holds throughout $\bar U$ hence making $u_k$ converge uniformly to some $u\in C(\bar U)$. But is it possible to further show $u\in C^2(U)$?

Comment: Yes, it holds. Proceed by showing that $u \ast \rho_\epsilon =u$ on compact subsets of your domain, for $\epsilon$ small enough, where those are standard mollifiers. Thus $u$ is smooth! Then you can take derivatives and prove that it’s harmonic (use mean value property, and assume $\Delta u> 0$ on a small ball to derive contradiction). See Evans for more details

Comment: If the mean value property in your post holds for all $x_0$ and all $r > 0$, then it certainly follows that $u$ is harmonic, even if $u$ is only assumed to be in $C^0$. The reason is that the mean value identity implies  successively better regularity than just $C^0$ for $u$.

Comment: @HansEngler if $u$ is known to be C2 then yes i know how to proceed. My problem was it was only known to be continuous. Nevertheless, David pointed out a very elegant approach above that easily solves my problem.

Comment: @DavidBowman thank you this is helpful! Actually Evans proved the smoothness of harmonic functions just starting from C0, using mollifiers and MVT.

Comment: Fixed a typo. It's enough to assume that $u \in C^0$. Or maybe less, e.g. $u \in L^1$ and the identity should hold in the sense of distributions. The argument given by David Bowman still goes through.

Comment: what means $\Delta u$ in this context? The Laplacian?

Comment: @Masacroso yes. I suppose it won't cause confusion in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any closed ball in the domain and restrict $u$ to its boundary. Use the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball) to extend it to a harmonic function $f$ on the ball. The difference $u-f$ also has the mean value property and vanishes on the boundary of the ball. Use these properties to conclude that both the maximum and minimum of $u-f$ must be $0$ on the ball. (It must be constant on any concentric sphere around a point where it has a maximum or minimum.)